# IBM Worklight: No SessionManager in calling Worklight adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Sometimes when Worklight adapter is invoked, the following error "No SessionManager" is encountered in server log. When the adapter is invoked again, result is returned. I have checked that the session ID remains the same.

May I know what is the possible reason to have this kind of error? Thanks!

Environment: Worklight 5.0.6.1

server log:

```
[2013-09-09 17:55:38] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure TestAdapter/getTestDataFWLSE0100E:  parameters:{
   "arr": [
   ]
}
No SessionManager
FWLSE0101E: Caused by: null
```

.metadata.log:

```
!ENTRY com.worklight.studio.plugin 4 0 2013-09-09 17:55:38.709
!MESSAGE FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure TestAdapter/getTestDataFWLSE0100E:  parameters:{
   "arr": [
   ]
}
No SessionManager
FWLSE0101E: Caused by: null
```

Comment: Can you please add to the questions the server.log and .metadata/.log files? Hopefully it will be there.

Comment: Hi Idan, basically the log is quite similar. Please see my update.

Comment: This is all you've found in both locations? (.metadata is a hidden folder)

Comment: I think some more background information is needed... what's the story behind these adapter requests? Does it also happen with other adapters? What's unique about this one?

Comment: What would you like to do with this question?

Answer (score 0):

This error is no longer reproduced in newer versions of Worklight. My suggestion to you is to update to the latest iFix of Worklight v5.0.6.2, or better yet - upgrade to MobileFirst Platform (previously Worklight) v6.3 / v7.0.